# (t)csh: how to "source" a gzip compressed text file?

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

I am looking for a Unix command that enables to "source" the text in a  `gzip` compressed text file.

If my explanation is not clear enough, I mean to a command that first unzips the file and then runs the original command on it, like `zgrep`, `zcat`, `zless`, etc. do

Thanks!

Comment: Which shell, specifically, are you using?

Comment: Since csh (and thus tcsh) isn't compliant with POSIX sh, I can't help you there at all. Please be more explicit when you're using a nonstandard shell -- most folks tend to assume that "unix shell" means POSIX.

Comment: ...I've edited the question to be more explicit there.

Comment: Question is still not super clear. `gunzip -c` uncompresses a .gz file to stdout, you can then pipe this to a command of your choice - eg `gunzip -c file.txt | grep "pattern"` or `gunzip -c file.txt | head -10`. Is this the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: did some quick tests and given my X years of csh experience, I kind of expected `eval "gunzip -c file2source"` to work. It printed out the each line `setenv myX x`, etc , but didn't execute them, i.e. `echo $myX` returned `Undefined Variable myX`. Also tried `eval eval` (just for luck). I think you'll have to unzip into a real file, and source that, then clean up. Good luck.

Comment: @JoshJolly, `source`ing in csh is the only way that you can achieve the `sh|bash|ksh` equivalent of `. envFile`, so that `envFile` is "run" in the same environment as the main shell script. It is a common technique to have environment variables issolated from the rest of the script's code, and helps with reducing errors in releases. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating shellter's approach, you could use

```
eval `gunzip -c file2source.gz|tr \\n \;`
```

for simple scripts. (I say simple because the command lines in the file are concatenated into one line.)

Other than that,

> to unzip into a real file, and source that,

seems to be the only way.